# Outlook won't add new email account (Mac)

Tags: macos, ms-office, office-365

I am running Outlook for Mac, version 16.78.3.

I am trying to add an additional email account to Outlook using the standard process (Settings -> Accounts -> Add an account). The account I am trying to add is a Microsoft 365 account and the process states that the 'Microsoft 365 account has been added' but when I am in Outlook the account is not present.

I suspect this may be occurring because I have had this email account running on this Mac in the past but have removed it and there may be some caching issue.

I have tried restarting Outlook, my Mac, etc with no success. I have also tried to investigate Outlook cache locations but haven't been able to find any solid information for this version of Mac / Outlook.

**EDIT**
I just found that the *old* Outlook displays this email account while the *new* outlook does not.